# Fist of the North Star Meridian charts

Tags: fist-of-the-north-star

Is it possible in a one run walkthrough to completely fill the Kenshiro Meridian Chart? Or does it need multiple runs?

Comment: I refuse to answer this question. After all, *you're already dead*.

Comment: ATATATAATAAATTTTTTTAAAAAATTAAT­­TATTAAAATATATATATTATATATATASA­A­

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's even possible, it's very difficult. By the way, the Meridian chart of a character is shared between "Story mode" and "Illusionary mode", so it is possible to improve the Meridian chart using points gained in "Illusionary mode".